# Saving NSString different

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sqlite

```
const char *sql = "SELECT Nome, Nome2, Nome3 FROM libretto"; 


sqlite3_stmt *select_statement; 

 if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &select_statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while(sqlite3_step(select_statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            //ricaviamo i valori letti dalla query
            nome = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(select_statement, 0)];
            nome2 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(select_statement, 1)];
            nome3 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(select_statement, 2)];
            // inseriamo tutti i valori letti in un unico oggetto
            NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:nome, @"Nome", nome2, @"Nome2", nome3, @"Nome3",nil];
            [listaTemp addObject:dictionary];

            //inserisco tutti i valori letti dei nomi in un unico oggetto
            [listaTemp addObject:dictionary];
        }
}

sqlite3_finalize(select_statement);
```

My problem is that every time in

```
name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: (char *) 
                sqlite3_column_text (select_statement, 0)];
```

I always read the last name in the database.

I want you to save me for example the first 3 names in different `NSString` in such a way that it can use to perform a my comparison.

```
const char *sql = "SELECT Nome, Nome2, Nome3 FROM libretto";

sqlite3_stmt *select_statement;
```

Comment: Plzzzzzzzzzz paste your code in well-formatted way. this time I did.

Comment: paste the sqlite query used for retrieving

Comment: const char *sql = "SELECT Nome, Nome2, Nome3 FROM libretto";
        
  sqlite3_stmt *select_statement;

Comment: You're saying that you loop multiple times, but at the end "nome" only contains the last name fetched?  Maybe you should put the names in an array??

Comment: @ Hot Licks  I need to make a comparison with isequaltostring